# ¿Cómo puedo conectar a mongodb de forma remota? - Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo que realizar la conexión a la base de datos de MongoDB por medio de nodejs, mi código para la conexión está definida así

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = "mongodb://<IP>:27017/prueba";

module.exports = () => {
    const connect = () => {
        mongoose.connect(
            url, {
                keepAlive: true,
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true
            },
            (err) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log("ERROR al conectar a la base de datos", err)
                } else{
                    console.log("Conexion a la base de datos")
                }
            }
        )
    }
    connect()
}
```

Pero al momento de correr el servidor en nodejs me sale el siguiente error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
```

Como puedo solucionar este error para que la URL que le paso de donde está el servidor de mongodb sea valido.

Comment: Cabe aclarar, que la configuración del mongo al que queremos conectar no contiene un usuario o contraseña y usa el mongo community. No se si esas cosas tengan algo que ver, debido a que la documentación o foros que he investigado, me aparece que se debe definir un usuario y contraseña, y otros señalan a usar mongo atlas.

Si bien es cierto, esto puede generar dudas, según el docente que nos encargo este proyecto, el lo ha podido hacer y la idea de está practica es poder conectar al mongo de su computador por medio de nuestros computadoras mientras estamos en una misma red.

Comment: ¿Haz leido la [documentación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) sobre los distintos formatos de cadena de conexión?